# Controlling how AngularJS replaces ngInclude or custom directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning AngularJS and noticed that Angular inserts template or partial HTML as a child of angular elements such as ng-include or custom directives.   In my case this breaks styling because Bootstrap styles do not select elements that are children of the directive.   So, I believe I'm either misunderstanding how to use directives or perhaps lack the terms for managing this behavior.

For example:

I want to specify just my custom directive and not associate a particular HTML type.

**Input:**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <my-dropdown-messages/>
</ul>
```

**Result:**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <my-dropdown-messages>
    <li class="dropdown my-intended">content</li>
  </my-dropdown-messages>
</ul>
```

**Desired result:**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li my-dropdown-messages class="dropdown my-intended">content</li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <form my-dropdown-messages class="my-intended">content</form>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to configure ng-include or custom directives so that the insertion sets the native html type, and does not put the partial html as a child of the angular directive?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Attribute directive instead of a Element directive

```
app.directive('myDropdownMessages', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', // Attribute directive
    templateUrl: 'my-dropdown.html'
  };
});
```

From AngularJS Docs

> When should I use an attribute versus an element? Use an element when you are creating a component that is in control of the template. The common case for this is when you are creating a Domain-Specific Language for parts of your template. Use an attribute when you are decorating an existing element with new functionality.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Thanks.  I think I'm getting closer.  Just learned about transclude, but the results are still a child of the original custom directive and not a replacement.

Comment: @MichaelPrescott the point is you can do `<li my-dropdown-messages>`

Answer (score 0):

using `replace: true` for your directive

but this property will be removed soon as very few scenarios where element replacement is required

refer to [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)